# iOS - blurred view with moving colors (like siri on iOS 9)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing an iOS application, and I would like to use a view that has randomized moving colors in the background, much like the view that is brought up when you use siri. The view used for siri seems to be slightly darker than a standard dark UIBlurEffect and there are random colors added that move slowly around the view whenever queries are made.

Below is an example of the background I'd like to create. There's some red in the top right of the blur and some green in the top left. Plus some light purple or something at the bottom.
[siri query view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX9fD.png)

The colors fade and new colors are added every queries, I honestly have no idea how to accomplish this, so any help that anyone has would be great.
Also, I'd like the answer to be in Objective-C if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to `UIBlurEffect` and it is key here. It provides a blur over a background, but doesn't specify what that background is. So, create that background to be a set of coloured views which appear (fade in perhaps), move around and then disappear. How you control the start and end location and the path the views follow is up to you. The effects view will apply the blurring for you and you can add whatever content you want in the foreground to the content of the effects view.